# Strong scalability plot, HPC

Tags: hpc, plotting, scaling

I have to create a **strong scalability plot**, which measures the **execution time** for a `numberOfThreads =1,2,4,8,16` with `size=1024`. Here is the table with the results after execution:

[image]

And here is the plot based on the table:

[image]

I don't know exactly when is a plot strong scalable and if this plot is a **strong scalability plot** ?

Comment: I suggest you to read https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/index.php/Measuring_Parallel_Scaling_Performance. There is also an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sensitive_scientist mentioned, [Measuring Parallel Scaling Performance](https://www.sharcnet.ca/help/index.php/Measuring_Parallel_Scaling_Performance) provides the information you want on how to calculate strong\weak scaling. I've plotted your data in a way I consider it the most informative: both execution timing and strong scaling.
Note:

1. In my opinion, it is preferred to plot the execution timing on a log-log plot. The dashed line shows ideal parallelization ($t$/$T$). The data suggests that you might want to add one more datapoint ($T=32$ threads) to show that the "Multiply" parallelization also breaks down (as well as "Block Multiply").
2. In a way, both of those plots serve the same purpose, but if they are detached it is hard to see the advantage of "Block Multiply" in an absolute sense - it is faster, though less parallel efficient.

[image: Execution timing]
[image: Strong Scaling]

For completeness, strong scaling as a function of # Threads ($T$)

$\text{strong scaling}(T)=\frac{t_1}{t_T*T}$,

where $t_1$ is the execution time for $1$ thread and $t_T$ is the execution time for $T$ threads.